# python minimalmodbus write_registers() writes wrong value to certain register

Tags: python, minimalmodbus

I tried to write a list of values [123,456,555,452,6121] using the write_registers() function of the minimalmodbus library using Python.
The registers start from register id 40184.
I got the error response ' No communication with the instrument (no answer)'.
When I tried reading the values it returned [123, **0**, 555, 452, 6121] as the output.

My code:

```
 import minimalmodbus
 import serial
 import time

 instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM10',1)  
 instrument.serial.baudrate = 19200
 instrument.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
 instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
 instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
 instrument.serial.timeout = 10
 instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU
 instrument.serial.timeout = 0.05

 try:
    values=[123,456,555,452,6121]
    instrument.write_registers(40184, values)
   
 except Exception as e:
     print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Comment: Is the register 40185 (the one you tried writing 456 to) a valid Modbus register? Is it a RW or a read-only register?
Can you try writing to only this register?
Is 456 a valid value to write to this register?

To me, it seems a problem of your Modbus slave device: either the register or the data you write to it is wrong/not allowed... I recommend that you read the device's Modbus description...

Comment: It is a read/write register. And also tried writing to this single register it is working. But not working with the write_registers function

Comment: that's strange... I guess the registers are also adjacent?
Maybe you could try testing with another range of registers to write to as well? And see what you can learn from that...

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe it's also valuable to play around with the timeout() and write_timeout() values.

Comment: The error message indicates that the Modbus slave device did not respond:
did none of the values get written, or did just one fail?
We need to figure out if one register failed, or if the complete call to write multiple registers failed. Do you know if the value of the other registers changed? Or did they just already have the correct data?
I'm asking this, because some Modbus slave devices might not support writing multiple registers at once, for example. Can you share the datasheet?